# Iterative way to "exactly" compute smallest eigenvalue of AA^T such that it is positive

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, fixed-point-theorems, symmetric-matrices

I have a matrix $A$ and I'm interested in its smallest singular value, i.e. the smallest eigenvalue of $B = A A^T$ (which is clearly positive).
Using common algorithms on $B$ to solve the eigenvalue problem for symmetric matrices I sometimes get negative smallest eigenvalues, clearly impossible.
I think this is due to approximation errors in the numerical process which accumulate (my matrices have a bad conditioning).

Is there an algorithm that I can use to converge to the smallest eigenvalue of $B$, whose precision improves with the number of iterations, and which only returns positive answers?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Is this true even if my matrix has only positive eigenvalues as in this case? Doesn't this imply that there is no numerically stable algorithm to compute the smallest eigenvalue *in general*? Do you have a reference to this?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Smallest non-negative is ok, as in my case I have almost certain guarantees (with respect to some sort of randomization that I'm performing) that the smallest eigenvalue is actually positive.

Comment: How about using SVD on A, and using that to obtain smallest eigenvalue of B? Getting smallest eigenvalue/singular value is generally the domain of rank-revealing factorizations (https://nhigham.com/2021/05/19/what-is-a-rank-revealing-factorization/), which tend to be more expensive

Comment: Well my problem is that SVD algorithms (at least those that I know of) typically cumulate numerical errors during orthogonalization. I've already tried those and they give me a negative eigenvalue, possibly due to the fact that the matrix that I have has a bad conditioning

Comment: To get eigenvalues of B you square singular values of A, so that should get rid of negative signs. But also, small negative values in finite precision are indistinguishable from zero, see implementation of scipy pinv for cutoff, it's something like 10^-7 * norm for float32